# I cannot get my methods math to work in my main class in my java program

Tags: java

I am attempting some array work for school. I am getting a user input for the size of the array, which will be filled with random elements. After I need to do some simple math; how many odd numbers, even numbers, sum of all etc. I have wrote everything, however the methods I wrote for the maths, does not compute to my main program, I am just getting "0"s for everything.
Excuse all of the comments, as you can probably tell, I have been trying multiple things.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //int sum, even, odd, min, max, size;
        //int [] intArray;
        //double average;
        //int even = 0, odd = 0, min = 0, max = 0, size = 0, sum = 0;
        //double average;
        System.out.print("Please enter a number for the array size (zero or greater):  ");
        int n=in.nextInt();
        if (n<0){
            System.out.println("ERROR: Number must be at least zero!!!");
        }else {
            IntArray mainArray = new IntArray(n);
        }
        //com.company.IntMath intMath = new com.company.IntMath(average, even, odd, min, max, size, sum);
        IntArray.IntMath intMath = new IntArray.IntMath();
        //intMath.average();
        //intMath.even();
        //intMath.getOdd();
        //intMath.getMin();
        //intMath.getMax();
        //intMath.getSize();
        //intMath.getSum();

        System.out.println("Average: " + intMath.average());  //print the average of the elements
        System.out.println("Even Count: " + intMath.even()); //prints the count of all even numbers
        System.out.println("Odd Count: " + intMath.odd()); //prints the count of all odd numbers
        System.out.println("Min: " + intMath.min()); //prints the min number
        System.out.println("Max: " + intMath.max()); //prints the max number
        System.out.println("Size: " + n); //prints the size of the array
        System.out.println("Sum: " + intMath.sum()); //prints the sum of all elements
        

    }
}
```

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class IntArray {
    private int[] intArray;


    public IntArray(int n) {

        Random randArray = new Random();
        int[] intArray = new int[n];
        intArray[0] = 0; //why does this not make the element 0 a 0?????????
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            intArray[i] = randArray.nextInt(50); //I was getting very big random numbers, so I set the max to 50
        }
        System.out.println("Set: " + Arrays.toString(intArray));


    }

    public static class IntMath {
        double average;
        int sum;
        int even;
        int odd;
        int max;
        int min;
        int size;
        int[] intArray;
        int n;

        //public IntMath() {//making a new constructor!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        //  this.average=average;
        // this.sum=sum;
        //  this.even=even;
        //  this.odd=odd;
        //  this.max=max;
        //  this.min=min;
        //  this.size=size;


        public double average () {
                 average = 0;
                 double total = 0;
                 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                     total = total + intArray[i];
                }
                 return average;
              }

        //          n should equal array length??????????

        public int sum() {
            //find the sum of all elements
            sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                sum += intArray[i];
            }
            return sum;
        }

        public int even() {
            even = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (intArray[i] % 2 == 0) {
                    even++;
                }
            }
            return even;
        }

        public int odd() {
            //odd = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (intArray[i] % 2 != 0) {
                    this.odd++;
                }
            }
            return odd;
        }

        public int max() {
            max = intArray[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if (intArray[i] > max) {
                    max = intArray[i];
                }
            }
            return max;
        }

        public int min() {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < intArray.length; j++) {
                    if (intArray[i] > intArray[j]) {
                        min = intArray[i];
                        intArray[i] = intArray[j];
                        intArray[j] = min;
                    }
                }
            }
            return min;
        }

        public int size() {
            size = n;
            return size;
      }

        }

    }
```

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this code.  It looks like you're just trying things at random without really considering what will happen. `intArray[0] = 0; //why does this not make the element 0 a 0?????????` Because in the next two lines, you create a `for` loop that starts by putting a different value at `intArray[0]`.

Comment: `int[] intArray = new int[n];` Also this re-definition of `intArray` in the constructor *hides* the value of `intArray` you declare about 4 lines before it as an instance variable.  It's a *local variable* so all the values you assign to it *go away* when the method ends.

Comment: You are correct, I am very new and still trying to learn. I do see what you mean though, and I corrected the first element, and now it is a zero. Thank you for that help.

Comment: I guess I am getting constructors and methods mixed up. I thought I declared the intArray in a constructor. I am taking an online course and I cannot get my professor to email back. The book is not that good. I do appreciate the help so far from you though.

Comment: One thing you need to be aware of is that once you declare a variable as an instance variable, you don't repeat it.  Right under `public class IntArray` you declare `private int[] intArray;`  Once you do that, you don't need to re-declare the `int[]` part, or you are *hiding* the instance variable.  You do need the `intArray = new int[n]` part (see the answer below) but if you add the `int[]` part to the beginning it messes you up.  Check your book carefully and that's how they should be doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are struggling with certain concepts so I would suggest you to look at this code and compare it with what you wrote to determine where things went wrong.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        IntArray mainArray = null;
        
        System.out.print("Please enter a number for the array size (zero or greater):  ");
        int size = in.nextInt();
        
        if (size < 0) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: Number must be at least zero!!!");
        } else {
            mainArray = new IntArray(size);
            
            IntArray.IntMath intMath = new IntArray.IntMath(mainArray.getIntArray());
            
            System.out.println("Average: " + intMath.average());  //print the average of the elements
            System.out.println("Even Count: " + intMath.even()); //prints the count of all even numbers
            System.out.println("Odd Count: " + intMath.odd()); //prints the count of all odd numbers
            System.out.println("Min: " + intMath.min()); //prints the min number
            System.out.println("Max: " + intMath.max()); //prints the max number
            System.out.println("Size: " + intMath.size()); //prints the size of the array
            System.out.println("Sum: " + intMath.sum()); //prints the sum of all elements
        }
        
        in.close();
    }
}
```

**IntArray.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class IntArray {
    private int[] intArray;

    public IntArray(int size) {
        Random randArray = new Random();
        intArray = new int[size];
        
        intArray[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            intArray[i] = randArray.nextInt(50);
        }
        
        System.out.println("Outer Array: " + Arrays.toString(intArray));

    }
    
    public int[] getIntArray() {
        return intArray;
    }

    public static class IntMath {
        double average;
        int sum;
        int even;
        int odd;
        int max;
        int min;
        int size;
        int[] intArray;

        public IntMath(int[] intArray) {
            this.intArray = intArray;
        }

        public double average() {
            average = 0;
            double total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                total += intArray[i];
            }
            
            average = total / intArray.length;
            
            return average;
        }


        public int sum() {
            sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                sum += intArray[i];
            }
            return sum;
        }

        public int even() {
            even = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                if (intArray[i] % 2 == 0) {
                    even++;
                }
            }
            return even;
        }

        public int odd() {
            for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                if (intArray[i] % 2 != 0) {
                    this.odd++;
                }
            }
            return odd;
        }

        public int max() {
            max = intArray[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                if (intArray[i] > max) {
                    max = intArray[i];
                }
            }
            return max;
        }

        public int min() {
            min = intArray[0];
            for(int i = 1; i < intArray.length; i++){ 
                  if(intArray[i] < min){ 
                    min = intArray[i]; 
                  } 
                }
            return min;
        }

        public int size() {
            size = intArray.length;
            return size;
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Please enter a number for the array size (zero or greater):  5
Set: [0, 45, 10, 20, 45]
Average: 24.0
Even Count: 3
Odd Count: 2
Min: 0
Max: 45
Size: 5
Sum: 120
```

Do accept this answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Modo, your solution did help, I am sure you knew that it would. I am still not sure where I went wrong. As you and the other commenter pointed out, I am struggling with multiple concepts. I hope I am not the only one who struggles at the beginning. Thank you very much, although I am still not sure what I exactly did wrong.

Comment: @iAmLost as much as I would love to help you learn by pointing out your mistakes, this is an ill-fit platform to do so. I would encourage you to keep your code and my code side by side and manually follow through to see how my code works. You can later do the same with your code and see where things are going wrong.

Comment: @iAmLost you can also open my profile and reach out to me on any of my social media accounts and I would be happy to explain it in detail in a DM.